# How does Spark manage stages?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to understand how jobs and stages are defined in spark, and for that I am now using the code that I found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EVbA.png) and spark UI. In order to see it on spark UI I had to copy and paste the text on the files several times so it takes more time to process.

Here is the output of spark UI:

[image: Jobs]

Now, I understand that there are three jobs because there are three actions and also that the stages are generated because of shuffle actions, but what I don't understand is why in the Job 1 stages 4, 5 and 6 are the same as stages 0, 1 and 2 of Job 0 and the same happens for Job 2.

How can I know what stages will be in more than a job only seeing the java code (before executing anything)? And also, why are stage 4 and 9 skipped and how can I know it will happen before executing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I understand that there are three jobs because there are three actions

I'd even say that there could have been more Spark jobs but the minimum number is `3`. It all depends on the implementation of transformations and the action used.

> I don't understand is why in the Job 1 stages 4, 5 and 6 are the same as stages 0, 1 and 2 of Job 0 and the same happens for Job 2.

Job 1 is the result of some action that ran on a RDD, `finalRdd`. That RDD was created using (going backwards): `join`, `textFile`, `map`, and `distinct`.

```
val people = sc.textFile("people.csv").map { line =>
  val tokens = line.split(",")
  val key = tokens(2)
  (key, (tokens(0), tokens(1))) }.distinct

val cities = sc.textFile("cities.csv").map { line =>
  val tokens = line.split(",")
  (tokens(0), tokens(1))
}

val finalRdd = people.join(cities)
```

Run the above and you'll see the same DAG.

[image: Job 6]

Now, when you execute `leftOuterJoin` or `rightOuterJoin` actions, you'll get the other two DAGs. You're using the previously-used RDDs to run new Spark jobs and so you'll see the same stages.

> why are stage 4 and 9 skipped

Often, Spark will skip execution of some stages. The grayed-out stages are ones already computed so Spark will reuse them and so make performance better.

[image: Job 7]

> How can I know what stages will be in more than a job only seeing the java code (before executing anything)?

That's what RDD lineage (graph) offers.

```
scala> people.leftOuterJoin(cities).toDebugString
res15: String =
(3) MapPartitionsRDD[99] at leftOuterJoin at <console>:28 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[98] at leftOuterJoin at <console>:28 []
 |  CoGroupedRDD[97] at leftOuterJoin at <console>:28 []
 +-(2) MapPartitionsRDD[81] at distinct at <console>:27 []
 |  |  ShuffledRDD[80] at distinct at <console>:27 []
 |  +-(2) MapPartitionsRDD[79] at distinct at <console>:27 []
 |     |  MapPartitionsRDD[78] at map at <console>:24 []
 |     |  people.csv MapPartitionsRDD[77] at textFile at <console>:24 []
 |     |  people.csv HadoopRDD[76] at textFile at <console>:24 []
 +-(3) MapPartitionsRDD[84] at map at <console>:29 []
    |  cities.csv MapPartitionsRDD[83] at textFile at <console>:29 []
    |  cities.csv HadoopRDD[82] at textFile at <console>:29 []
```

As you can see yourself, you will end up with 4 stages since there are 3 shuffle dependencies (the edges with the numbers of partitions).

Numbers in the round brackets are the number of partitions that `DAGScheduler` will eventually use to create task sets with the exact number of tasks. One `TaskSet` per stage.